# Unit test coverage report for tests written using unittest and pytest package

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, python-unittest, coverage.py

In the project that I am currently working on, I have few of my colleagues who have written unit tests using unittest package and some using pytest package. When I run unit tests in CI pipeline, I invoke all of the unit tests. But, we now also need to get overall code coverage package. So, I have updated unit test invocation script by adding coverage (Please see script snippet below). But, I see that when I run below script I get coverage output of `coverage run -a -m pytest -v -m unittests` (line 7 below) only not the tests run before. But, if I remove the line `coverage run -a -m pytest -v -m unittests` (line 7 below), I get output of previous unit tests.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -xe
coverage run -m unittest test_a.py
coverage run -a -m unittest test_b.py
coverage run -a -m unittest test_c.py
...
cd process/tests/
coverage run -a -m pytest -v -m unittests
coverage report -m --omit=*/venv/*
```

coverage only reports the output of `coverage run -a -m pytest -v -m unittests` ignoring the previously run unit tests.

Can I please know how can I get a single report for all unit tests in above scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used combine command to fix the problem:

https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cmd.html#cmd-combine